# How to create a system tray popup message with Django? (Windows)

Tags: django, windows, azure

I have a web app, in Django, Azure. I want to click a button and send a notification to another users (user info stored in db). This has to appear on their notification bar when they are logged in. How can I initiate it? I know there are several ways to do it, please suggest the best option.

Answer (score 1):

You can use notification queue and websocket for this use case. This is common pattern used for pushing notifications back to frontend applications.

Comment: can you add more details?